# Terraform - dynamic nested loops

Tags: for-loop, google-cloud-platform, terraform, nested-loops

I am trying to create a nested loop to create Firewall rules in GCP. I have a `locals` variable that looks something like this:

```
local.firewall_definitions
{
  "10.0.0.0/8" = [
    {
      "port" = "80"
      "protocol" = "tcp"
    },
    {
      "port" = "443"
      "protocol" = "tcp"
    },
    {
      "port" = "9000"
      "protocol" = "udp"
    },
  ]
  "99.99.99.99/32" = [
    {
      "port" = "30000"
      "protocol" = "tcp"
    },
    {
      "port" = "1822"
      "protocol" = "tcp"
    },
    {
      "port" = "1823"
      "protocol" = "udp"
    },
  ]
}
```

What I am essentially trying to do, is to loop through this variable in 2 ways:

1. Create a new `google_compute_firewall` rule once for every different CIDR in this list (sometimes it may be 1, sometimes there could be 10)
2. Within each CIDR, loop through the variable for every port & protocol to create each `allow` rule

My `main.tf` looks like this:

```
resource "google_compute_firewall" "firewalls" {
  for_each = local.firewall_definitions

  name          = var.name
  network       = var.network
  project       = var.project
  target_tags   = var.targets
  source_ranges = var.ranges

  dynamic "allow" {
    for_each = local.firewall_definitions[*]

    content {
      protocol = each.value[*].protocol
      ports    = each.value[*].port
    }
  }
}
```

The issue is (I think) that I am trying to loop through using splat, but I get errors like

> each.value is tuple with 3 elements.
> Inappropriate value for attribute "protocol": string required.

I think this is because `each.value[*].protocol` currently equates to

```
"tcp",
"tcp",
"udp",
```

Whereas Terraform expects only a single protocol in `string` form, not a `tuple` of 3 elements.

Does anyone have any ideas about the correct way to achieve a nested loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not actually a nested loop because the key is ignored in the temporary iterator variable in the lambda scope, and as such the structure could be flattened completely. The first problem with the implementation is that the `for_each` in the dynamic block is iterating on the entire `local.firewall_definitions`. In the resource scope, for each iteration on `local.firewall_definitions` the `key` will be the unused ip address, and the `value` is the `list(object(string))` assigned to it. We can update the dynamic block to iterate on the `list` value (dynamic blocks are allowed to iterate on the `list` type with the `for_each` meta-argument unlike `resource`):

```
dynamic "allow" {
  for_each = each.value

  content {
    protocol = each.value[*].protocol
    ports    = each.value[*].port
  }
}
```

The second problem with the implementation is that the value assigned to the `for_each` meta-argument in the dynamic block is being ignored completely in the resource. Now that the dynamic block is iterating on the `list` of `object` with the `port` and `protocol` for the specific ip address `key`, we need to access the protocol and port for each `object` in the iterated `list`:

```
dynamic "allow" {
  for_each = each.value

  content {
    protocol = allow.value.protocol
    ports    = allow.value.port
  }
}
```

and the desired result is achieved. Documentation for the [for_each meta-argument](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html) and [dynamic blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html) can be viewed for further information.

Comment: Amazing, thanks for explaining Matt. If you saw my earlier (now deleted) comment, please ignore it, I had a typo! This solution works well, and after a bit more reading, I'm pretty sure I get how it works.